# JavaScript Queue Implantation

Tags: javascript, data-structures

```
//create a Node class that will represent elements/nodes in the Queue
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }
}
//creates a Queue class to store the elements/nodes of the Queue
class Queue {
  constructor() {
    this.first = null;
    this.last = null;
    this.size = 0;
  }
  //enqueues a node
  enqueue(val) {
    let node = new Node(val);
    if (this.size === 0) {
      this.first = node;
      this.last = node;
    } else {
      this.last.next = node;
      this.last = node;
    }
    return this.size++;
  }
  //dequeues a node 
  dequeue() {
    if (!this.first) {
      return null;
    }
    let temp = this.first;
    if (this.first === this.last) {
      this.last = null;
    }
    this.first = this.first.next;
    this.size--;
    return temp.value;
  }
}
```

I was following an article on medium on how to implement stacks and queues with JavaScript.
I was lost when it came to queues specifically the way the author implemented enqueing. On the last bits of the method "enqueue", he writes

```
{
   this.last.next = node;
   this.last = node;
}
```

Wouldn't the previous item be overwritten by this implementation? What Im i missing?

Comment: Put breakpoint there and see by yourself. Maybe it's just bug? Maybe intensional? Maybe prototypical inheritance?

Comment: I got it, reading the problem slower helped. Each previous value would have the next value as its next and we reset the program to the last item by doing this.last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.last.next` will be `null`, there is nothing after the last item.

`this.last.next = node;` creates a link from the current last node to the new item, then `this.last = node;` sets the current last node to the node that was just inserted. The previous last node is still in the linked list though.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't intend to add the same object to the queue more than once a javascript Set implements a queue.

Enque is simply adding the element to the set.

Deque is just (you may first want to check the set isn't empty)

```
const [top] = set //using destructuring assignment 
set.delete(top)
```

This works as set is guaranteed to return elements in insertion order.